# Raspberry Pi communication hangs on accept()

Tags: c++, tcp, raspberry-pi

I have 2 raspberry pis I want to send some data between to initiate a function simultaneously on both of them, the connection between the two is an ethernet cable and neither is connected to the internet.

I am having an issue where my server code hangs once it hits accept. I've included both the server and client code. I am using the IP of the Pi running the server code in the client code. I believe it is an issue of either the client not sending the connection to the correct place or the server is not being told the correct location where to receive it.

The code is based on the example code here http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html.

Server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
//#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     printf("Sock \n");
     socklen_t clilen;
     printf("clilen \n");
     char buffer[256];
     printf("buffer \n");
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     printf("struct \n");
     int n;
     printf("n \n");

     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     printf("Sockfd \n");

     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     printf("bzero \n");
     portno = 6666;
     printf("port \n");
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     printf("afinet \n");
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     printf("inadder any \n");
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     printf("htons \n");

     printf("listen \n");
     cout << listen(sockfd,5) << "\n";
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     cout << "&clilen: " << &clilen << "\n";
     cout << "clilen: " << clilen << "\n";

     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     printf("newsock \n");

     bzero(buffer,256);
     printf("bezero 2 \n");
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     printf("read \n");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);


     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     printf("write \n");

     return 0;
}
```

Server Output:

```
Sock
clilen
buffer
struct
n
Sockfd
bzero
port
afinet
inadder any
htons
listen
0
&clilen: 0x7eeaaf0c
clilen: 16
```

Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
//#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    printf("sock \n");

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    printf("sockaddr \n");
    struct in_addr ipv4addr;
    printf("ipv4 \n");
    struct hostent *server;
    printf("hostent \n");

    char buffer[256];
    printf("buffer \n");

    portno = 6666;
    printf("port \n");
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    printf("sockfd \n");
    if (sockfd < 0)
        printf("ERROR opening socket");
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "169.254.59.109", &ipv4addr);
    printf("inet \n");
    server = gethostbyaddr(&ipv4addr, sizeof ipv4addr, AF_INET);
    cout << "server: " << server << "\n";
    printf("server \n");
    //if (server == NULL) {
        //fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        //exit(0);
    //}
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    printf("bzero \n");
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    printf("af \n");
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,(char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_length);
    printf("bcopy \n");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    printf("htons \n");
    cout << "connect: " << (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))) << "\n";
    cout << "sockfd: " << sockfd << "\n";
    cout << "struct: " << (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr << "\n";
    cout << "serv: " << sizeof(serv_addr) << "\n";
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        printf("ERROR connecting\n");


    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    printf("write \n");
    if (n < 0)
         printf("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    printf("read \n");
    if (n < 0)
         printf("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Client Output:

```
sock
sockaddr
ipv4
hostent
buffer
port
sockfd
inet
server: 0x76d3c5a4
server
bzero
af
bcopy
htons
connect: -1
sockfd: 3
struct: 0x7ea32ef0
serv: 16
ERROR connecting
Please enter the message: hello
```

Comment: You call `connect` twice, both fail. It should be called only once. Please check the exact error using `perror` or similar.  Given that the connection attempt does not seem to reach the server it is likely that either IP or port are wrong or that there is some firewall blocking connections or that the ethernet connection does not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I'm still having the same issue. I changed it to call `connect` once, the perror gave me connection refused, following that I checked the IP and port and they are the correct ones as far as I can tell. I used `hostname -I` to get the IP and assigned the portno myself. I also enabled and restarted ssh. Do you have any other ideas as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Connection refused means that the other side or something in between does not allow the connection. This means that there is no listener on the other side or that some firewall (iptables) is blocking the connection. Try to connect with another application like netcat to the target and see if this works at all. If not replace the listener with something like netcat and see if the connection works. If still not there are likely firewall rules or you've given the wrong target. Also make sure that your code works on localhost before having the additional complexity of two networked systems.